# Error al ejecutar proyecto PHP con XAMP en MAC

Tags: php, xampp, macos

Tengo el problema al ejecutar un proyecto PHP en XAMP de MAC

```
Warning: require_once(../app/modelos/modeloUsuarios.php.): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/trabajo/app/librerias/Controlador.php on line 11

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../app/modelos/modeloUsuarios.php.' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/trabajo/app/librerias/Controlador.php on line 11
```

Comment: Hola @Daniel no uso mac pero si linux y en una ocasión me sucedió algo parecido y era un problema de permiso en el caso de linux tuve que darle 755 y colocarlo en el grupo de mi usuario de trabajo estos permiso los di recursivo. Espero que te sea de utilidad. Gracias

Comment: Si me suena algo como eso, como podria cambiar eso?

Comment: En el caso de mac no tengo mucha experiencia por uso linux. los comandos que uso para eso son: **chmod** para los permisos y **chown** para el propietario. Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Es verdad, te agradezco mucho, voy a buscar los comandos y cuando los tenga los comparto para tener un historico jejeje